# On After Render a Modal razor component start a JavaScript

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor, blazor

I have a blazor app with an razor component as modal open by

Open the modal.razor

```
<ModalScan @ref="ModalScan"><p>Scanner</p></ModalScan>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ScanStart">Start Scann</button>

@code{
ModalScan ModalScan;

void ScanStart()
    {
        ModalScan.Show();
    }
}
```

the modal.razor

```
    @if (_Show)
{
    <div class="modal fade show"  style="display: block;">
        <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 90%;" @>
            <div id="modal_fullscreen" class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Scanner</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="Show">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">                    
                    <form>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div id="loadingMessage">Unable to access video stream </div>
                                <canvas style="width: 100%;" id="canvas" hidden></canvas>
                                <div id="output" hidden>
                                    <div id="outputMessage">No detected.</div>
                                    <div hidden>
                                        <input type="text" id="outputData" value="@CurrentValue"
                                               @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs __e) => CurrentValue = __e.Value.ToString())" />
                                    </div>                                   
                                </div>


                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="ScanResume">Scan</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="Show">Abort</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="saveChanges">Ok</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
}
```

After this modal.razor is load, i will start a js-Script.
I can only start with a button, then the DOM is not loading when 
i invoke the Javascript on the Show() void.

On a razor page works it with:

```
 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {            
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("startScanner");
        }
    }


 public async void Show()
    {
    _Show = !_Show;
    if (_Show)
    {

    }
}
```

but not on the modal. 
Is there any event to check if modal is load complete from razor componetes in my modal?

Comment: This may have something to do with server-side rendering.  Components can be pre-rendered on the server and there is no JS.  Try to turn it off and see what happens.

Comment: You haven't shown us what the Show() method does....please include that